# How to increase text box width and height based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to render the text box based on the value provided. For example if the value exceeds above the normal width, I need to render the text box to show the full characters on keyup action. Also the maximum/minimum size of the text box was restricted. Min width = 300px, Max width = 400. If the value exceeds above this width, I want to render it as text area with two rows.

What are the possible ways to customize the text box to render the full value?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript